# CSS Hover Option

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, styles

I learn and use css and css3 around 2 years but i dont know 1 thing and i cant find a really good answer or fix for this.

So here is an example :

I created a div and inside this div we have a link (its a button).

When i hover my mouse on the div this div will change the bg-color but the link not because im above the div... **So when im above the div this div and the link too will change the color or background** this is what i need... But how to do it ? I never used this but now i think i'll need this for my next work  :))

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy to achieve using css: ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69EE5/2/))

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="button">some text</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container:hover{
    background-color:red;
}
.container:hover .button{ // selector for .button which is in a hovered .container
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div id="test">
  <a href="#">A link</a>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
div#test:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
div#test:hover a {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is the following CSS selector:

```
div:hover a{
    /* your styles here */
}
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jF4Gw/)**

Answer (score -1):

Hope this [**demo link**](http://jsfiddle.net/FWVQ6/) will work for you.

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }
body {
    font:normal 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    }
ul, li, ol {
    list-style-type:none;
    }

.wrapper {
    width:95%;
    padding:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px  solid green;
}
.spacer {
    clear:both;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
    height:0;
    }
.wrapper:hover {
    background-color:#999999;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
.btmoOne {
    width:170px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#FF0000;
    padding:10px;
    }
.wrapper:hover .btmoOne {
    background-color:#006600;
    }
```

Comment: Why downvote for this answer,though it is in accordance with OP's requirement